# How to show 24h time in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a google sheet that feeds from a form. I want to capture the timestamp in a separate cell when another cell is changed. I can get it to display the time now but I need it to be in military time.

```
var timezone = "GMT-4"
var timestamp_format = "hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format.
```

I expect the output to say `13:15:55`, but the actual is `1:15:55`.

Answer (score 0):

Google's App Script uses the standard JavaScript `Date` object when returning forms. Here is how to get what you want from a `Date` object.

```
var resultFromForm = ...
var time = resultFromForm.toTimeString().substring(0, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just change internal formatting like:

[image: 0]